# MEF plugin calling another plugin with same interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, plugins, mef, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to make a (my first MEF) system in which plugins can be recursive, i.e. my main system calls a MEF plugin with a standard interface, which on its own can then call another (or several) plugin(s), and so on.

When testing though, my plugin does not call the underlying plugin, but starts processing itself (creating a loop).

Any idea how I can prevent this?

Interface:

```
public interface IConnector
{
    XDocument Run(object serviceCredentials, object connectorIds, object connectorKeys);
}
```

My main plugin inherits the interface, and defines the import for the next (The subplugin has the same definition):

```
[Export(typeof(IConnector))]
public class Connector : IConnector
{
    [Import(typeof(IConnector))]
    private IConnector connector;
    ....
```

The called plugin is initiated (in the Run method of the main plugin):

```
public XDocument Run(object serviceCredentials, object connectorIds, object connectorKeys)
{
    string calledConnector = Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "subplugin.dll");
    AssemblyCatalog assembyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(calledConnector));
    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(assembyCatalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
    ....
```

The container should now contain just one plugin, the subplugin.dll.
I call the method 'Run' which is in the interface to invoke the subplugin method:

```
XDocument something = connector.Run(serviceCredentials, connectorids, connectorkeys);
```

But, instead of running the subplugin code, the 'Run' method in my main plugin activates, which keeps activating itself.

When I remove the [Export(typeof(iConnector)] in the main plugin, the subplugin is activated, but I want my main plugin to be able to be called in the same manner.

Being new to MEF I am stuck as to how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833616(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify your intent, otherwise MEF will go into an infinite loop or pick the Connector as it exposes IConnector itself.

Some more info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example

```
[Export("Container", typeof(IConnector))]
public class Connector : IConnector
{
    [Import("Component", typeof(IConnector))]
    private IConnector connector;
    ....
```

**UPDATE**

So after giving it some thought, here is an example of metadata based approach, and one that also limits the number of expensive catalog operations.

The `IConnector`

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Common
{
    public interface IConnector
    {
        XDocument Run(object serviceCredentials, object connectorIds, object connectorKeys);

        void Identify();
    }
}
```

The metadata attribute `ConnectorMetadata`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace Common
{
    [MetadataAttribute]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class ConnectorMetadata : ExportAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public ConnectorMetadata(string name):base(typeof(IConnector))
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public ConnectorMetadata(IDictionary<string, object> metaData) : base(typeof (IConnector))
        {
            Name = Convert.ToString(metaData["Name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

The lazy singleton for `PluginsCatalog`

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Common;

namespace Common
{
    public class PluginsCatalog
    {
        [ImportMany]
        public Lazy<IConnector, ConnectorMetadata>[] Connectors;

        private static readonly Lazy<PluginsCatalog> LazyInstance = new Lazy<PluginsCatalog>(() => new PluginsCatalog());

        private PluginsCatalog()
        {
            var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path, "*plugin.dll");

            var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalog, directoryCatalog);

            var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
        }

        public static PluginsCatalog Instance { get { return LazyInstance.Value; } }

        public IConnector GetConnector(string name)
        {
            var match = Connectors.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name.Equals(name));
            return match == null ? null : match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The "Primary" `IConnector`

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Common;

namespace Common
{
    [ConnectorMetadata("Primary")]
    public class Connector : IConnector
    {

        public XDocument Run(object serviceCredentials, object connectorIds, object connectorKeys)
        {
            PluginsCatalog.Instance.GetConnector("Sub").Identify();
            return default(XDocument);
        }

        public void Identify()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName);
        }

    }
}
```

The "Sub" `IConnector`

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Common;

namespace SubPlugin
{
    [ConnectorMetadata("Sub")]
    public class SubConnector:IConnector
    {
        public XDocument Run(object serviceCredentials, object connectorIds, object connectorKeys)
        {
            return default(XDocument);
        }

        public void Identify()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the program itself:

```
namespace SOMEF
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connector = PluginsCatalog.Instance.GetConnector("Primary");
            connector.Identify();
            connector.Run(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
SOMEF.Connector
SubPlugin.SubConnector
```

Hope this helps ... :)

Comment: That is part of the solution, it works for the main plugin not to be called.
But, I would like more subplugins to be able to be called with the same interface. E.g. the connector should serve both "Component1" and "Component2", in fact an infinite range that could be extended as more plugins are developed using the same interface. 

Is this possible?

Comment: I fixed it by not using Contracts, but instead referring to the (in my situation unique) namespace when calling the Run method.

`if (connector.GetType().Namespace.Equals(GetKey("companysource"), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
 something = connector.Run(serviceCredentials, connectorids, connectorkeys);`

Comment: Have you considered other IoC libraries? From what I read in your code, you might be able to achieve the same, but much easier with Ninject. MEF is not the only choice.

Comment: Another thought, having re-read your comments, in my case, when multiple plugins are involved, I use MEF metadata attributes to identify which of the IConnector classes I need. Have you considered it?

Comment: There should be no need to recompose on every "Run". It's expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691(v=vs.110).aspx

With exmplanation how named exports are used

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Import("MajorRevision")]
    public int MajorRevision { get; set; }
}

public class MyExportClass
{ 
    [Export("MajorRevision")] //This one will match.
    public int MajorRevision = 4;

    [Export("MinorRevision")]
    public int MinorRevision = 16;
}
```